# Generate and View Excel files

Tags: c#, excel, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm looking for solution (possibility) to generate (and view) Excel files from my Windows Store App.

Unfortunately, I can't target [DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.5.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/2.5.0) to Windows Store app

Also I require full functionality Excel docs (not csv), and can't use [Export To CSV](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Export-To-CSV-Sample-b31b50cf).

Maybe someone knows solution: How generate excel files in Windows Store App?

Answer (score 1):

The format is published, so you could create the files using custom code. While it's not ideal, as you mentioned, the current SDK isn't supported in a Windows Store application due to a dependency on an assembly that isn't available.

There are apparently a few simple open source libraries and paid libraries that replicate some of the functionality of the full SDK. You'll have better luck with open source if it has targeted Silverlight or the Windows Phone as that code won't have a dependency in the full .NET framework.

The best viewer for Excel would be Excel. There may be a third party option, but the best consistent experience would be to launch the full application.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I support you - the full application is better. But in my app I need to generate some excel files. You sad, that you know few open source and paid libraries. Can you provide which exactly do you mean? thanks

Comment: (As questions that ask for off-site resources aren't a good fit for StackOverflow, if you do a search, you should be able to find the same ones I found).

Comment: You might also consider using a web server to generate the files if a component isn't an option (send the data to the web server, and using the OpenXML SDK, generate the file and return it).